# Interactive, non interactive shells and expansion

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I execute the test `[[ ! (-z "") ]]` interactively, or non interactively by `bash -c '[[ ! (-z "") ]]'`, I obtain the same result, that is `echo $?` gives me `1`.

But if I forget a space in the above expression, giving `[[ !(-z "") ]]`, I don't obtain the same result anymore. More precisely,

```
set -x; [[ !(-z "") ]]; echo $?
```

gives me

```
+ [[ -n !(-z ) ]]
+ echo 0
0
```

while

```
bash -c 'set -x; [[ !(-z "") ]]; echo $?'
```

gives me

```
+ [[ -z '' ]]
+ echo 1
1
```

So my question is: why interactive and non interactive shells don't give the same expansion, and so the same result in this case (or other similar ones)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite complicated.

At first please note globbing doesn't work inside `[[ ]]`. If you run something like

```
set -x; [[ / == /* ]]; echo $?
```

then you will see `/*` doesn't expand there like in `echo /*`.

Now there is `extglob` shell option. It looks like in your case it's enabled in interactive shells, disabled in non-interactive ones. (Compare [Where is bash's “shopt extglob” turned on for my interactive shell?](https://askubuntu.com/q/634397/693277))

> If the `extglob` shell option is enabled using the `shopt` builtin, several extended pattern matching operators are recognized. […]
>
> `!(pattern-list)`
> Matches anything except one of the given patterns.

([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching))

Inside `[[ ]]` the operator is recognized but it doesn't expand. How do I know? I can make the shell not recognize it:

```
shopt -u extglob
set -x; [[ !(-z "") ]]; echo $?
```

Now I get `-bash: !: event not found`. This indicates `!` has different meaning:

> `!`
> Start a history substitution, except when followed by a space, tab, the end of the line, `=` or `(` (when the `extglob` shell option is enabled using the `shopt` builtin).

([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Event-Designators))

This differs between interactive and non-interactive shells:

> When the shell is running interactively, it changes its behavior in several ways.
>
> […]
> 7. Command history […] and history expansion […] are enabled by default.

([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Interactive-Shell-Behavior))

Next step is to disable history:

```
shopt -u extglob
set +o history
set -x; [[ !(-z "") ]]; echo $?
```

And here you go, the result is like in your non-interactive shell.

---

Can we do this the other way around? Can we make a non-interactive shell behave like an interactive one?

At first let's check what happens when a new shell is forced to be interactive:

```
bash -ic 'set -x; [[ !(-z "") ]]; echo $?'
```

It behaves as expected, like your interactive shell. Now let's enable `extglob` for non-interactive shell:

```
bash -c 'shopt -s extglob; set -x; [[ !(-z "") ]]; echo $?'
```

And it doesn't work! It still behaves like your non-interactive shell with `extglob` disabled. The explanation is simple, yet not obvious: globbing is performed for the entire line before `shopt` does its job. When the option gets changed it's already too late. Let's split the command into two lines then:

```
bash -c 'shopt -s extglob
         set -x; [[ !(-z "") ]]; echo $?'
```

Now it behaves like your interactive shell.

---

The last mystery is this:

> ```
> + [[ -n !(-z ) ]]
> ```

Where did `-n` come from in your interactive shell? My hypothesis is based on the observation that `[[ "random-string" ]]` is treated as `[[ -n "random-string" ]]` (check it with `set -x`). I *guess* when you run `[[ !(-z "") ]]` and `extglob` is enabled, the fact that the `!( )` operator is recognized but not expanded makes the entire `!(-z "")` string stay there as one word, i.e. your command becomes something like

```
set -x; [[ "!(-z )" ]]; echo $?
```

This command (in interactive or non-interactive shell) behaves like the one you run in the interactive shell.